# How to achieve the Google Analytics cookie in other's website?

Tags: php, google-analytics

Google analytics will send the message included in the cookie to a small image in google-analytics.com, but will it do it when I use cURL to send a GET request to a website with analytics code?

If it does, how could I get the Google analytics cookie using PHP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will not - google analytics code is evaluated by user's browser. And you just fetch the page html and don't process it.